# Why can't the array elements be accessed? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filereader

For some reason when elements are pushed to an array in the FileReader.onload event function, the elements of that array are later inaccessible. Consider the following code:

```
scope.targets = [];

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

        reader.onload = function(e){
              scope.targets.push(e.target.result);
        };
 }

 console.log(scope.targets);
 console.log(scope.targets[0]);
```

This is the result of the console.log() outputs in Google Chrome Browser.
As you can see scope.targets reveals that there's an element of type string.
However, scope.targets[0] is undefined. Why is this happening? Is there another way to access the element?

[image]

---

**************************UPDATE*************************************

---

Here's a solution. Thank You Ashwin Balamohan and nnnnn for your answers, it led me to find a solution. I found what I was looking for here [How to implement Progress Bar and Callbacks with async nature of the FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443440/how-to-implement-progress-bar-and-callbacks-with-async-nature-of-the-filereader)

**The Solution is:**

```
scope.targets = [];

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

        reader.onload = function(e){
              scope.targets.push(e.target.result);
              if(i == files.length){
                    callback();
              }
        };
 }

 var callback = function(){
     console.log("scope.targets:");
     console.log(scope.targets);
     console.log("scope.targets[0]:");
     console.log(scope.targets[0]);
 }
```

Comment: due to the nature of your request, we can't reproduce this easily. it would be better for you to make a jsFiddle or something we can use to see the problem.

Comment: The array is populated within a function that runs asynchronsously and the `console.log()` statements run before that happens. Depending on the browser that you are using, the console may keep a reference to an object that is logged such that by the time you expand the array in the console it does have values in it even though it was empty when logged. Try saying `console.log(JSON.stringify(scope.targets))` at that same point and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one

```
scope.targets = {};

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

        reader.onload = function(e){
              scope.targets[i] = (e.target.result);
        };
 }

console.log(scope.targets);
console.log(scope.targets[0]);
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

The code is executing asynchronously. See comments below

```
scope.targets = [];

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

        // below is an asynchronous call
        reader.onload = function(e){
              scope.targets.push(e.target.result);
        };
 }

 // the asynchronous calls above may or may not be complete by the time you get here
 console.log(scope.targets);
 console.log(scope.targets[0]);
```

What you can do is to modify your `reader.onload` function so that it performs the `console.log` in the callback:

```
scope.targets = [];

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

        // below is an asynchronous call
        reader.onload = function(e){
              scope.targets.push(e.target.result);
              // log out the array here, instead
              console.log(scope.targets);
        };
 }
```

Comment: Yes, putting the console.log(scope.targets) in the reader.onload function works. However, I need the scope.targets array data outside of the reader.onload function.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I was hoping for a solution though.

Comment: Great, @Ellioticus. I glad I was able to help in the end.